# What methodology/algorithm does cv::absdiff() use?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

What methodology/algorithm does OpenCV's `cv::absdiff(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst)` use?

For a 1 channel `Mat` does it compute the colour distance between each cell/voxel of `src1` with the voxel at the same position of `src2`? Does it compute the intensity difference or colour difference or other? Is it's worst-case, average and best-case runtime O(N) (where N is the number of voxels in the `Mat`)? How is the absolute difference calculated?

In terms of runtime complexity is `cv::canny()` slower or faster than `cv::absdiff()`? Is the speed difference significant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`absdiff`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6fef31bc8c4071cbc114a758a2b79c14) is a **simple operation** on a matrix. It computes the absolute value of the difference for each pixel, for each channel.

The operation is:

```
// pseudocode
Mat src1, src2, dst; 
...
for each row : r
    for each column : c
        for each channel : ch
            dst(r,c,ch) = abs(src1(r,c,ch) - src2(r,c,ch))
```

You can see that the complexity is O(N), where `N = rows * cols * channels`, since you have to scan the full matrix. This is also *highly optimizable*.

[canny](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) instead is an **algorithm**, with a [lot of steps involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector). 
I'm not aware of its complexity, but it's at least O(N) with an `N` much greater than `absdiff`.

So, `canny` is much slower than `absdiff`, but it's not a fair comparison.

---

OpenCV doesn't have the concept of *voxel*.